# Does "Answer your own question" automatically accept my answer?

Tags: support, self-answer

If I use the `Answer your own question` checkbox, does it accept the answer immediately?

Comment: What's the point of downvoting it on meta, though? It is not a feature suggestion (aside from maybe suggestion to document it in more detail).

Comment: Lack of research perhaps?

Comment: This question _is_ research. I used this option when posting it. There is no SO sandbox as far as I know.

Comment: I'm merely guessing. I'm not the downvoter. Fact is though that all the information you were asking for was already available on the site.

Comment: What I wanted to verify is that it is consistent with the 48 hour rule — I think it should be closed as duplicate if that was already answered. I did not find any specific documentation that would say it is.

Comment: Of course it would be kind of weird if it was inconsistent, but real life apps can have a lot of special cases for good reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because we have to wait for at least [48 hours to accept own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) after the question is asked.

Answer (score -3):

No (based on the status of this answer).